# Almost Lindelöf spaces.

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, lindelof-spaces

I'm working on the study of almost Lindelöf spaces and I'm stuck searching a counterexample. First, the definition.

> Let $X$ be a topological space. We say that $X$ is an almost Lindelöf space if for every open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$ there exist a countable subset $\mathcal{U}_0$ of $\mathcal{U}$ such that $$X=\bigcup_{U\in\mathcal{U}_0} \text{cl}(U)$$

In general, the property doesn't preserve to closed subspaces. The example is $\kappa\mathbb{N}$ (the Katetov extension of $\mathbb{N}$) because is $H-$closed (and therefore almost Lindelöf) and $\kappa\mathbb{N}\setminus\mathbb{N}$ is a uncountable closed discrete subspace. My question is: is there another topological space different from Katetov extension that proves that the property of being almost Lindelöf doesn't preserve by take closed subspaces? I really appreciate any help you can provide me.

Comment: Note that a regular almost Lindelöf space is Lindelöf, so you need something between regular and Hausdorff, probably. (like $\kappa\Bbb N$)

Comment: I know. In fact, I want another example different from $\kappa\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Why do you want another when you’ve got a perfectly fine one?

Comment: It's only my curiosity for find another different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example 3.3 in [this overview paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e4d2/dd721f20cf75485138796f208d7a93e0d536.pdf) is almost Lindelöf with an uncountable discrete closed subspace.